# GSA Search Result Logs

Tags: google-search-appliance

I am using GSA Appliance 7.2
We are planning to improve search experience for that I want to analyze search logs, In search logs we are getting only User Ip and search query link.
Other than this I want which link user clicked and in which page he got his search result like in 1st page or second page etc.

Please help me to get detailed search logs.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the possibility to generate search reports in GSA admin console under **Reports > Search** Reports. These reports are sort of a summary in which you can see the following details:

- Number of search queries per day;
- Number of search queries per hour;
- Top keywords;
- Top search queries;
- Position of clicks;
- Page of clicks;
- Top clicked URLs;
- Top IPs of clients which are used to perform search queries.

With **Reports > Serving Logs**, you can per-query track clients and which search results where returned by GSA, but you can't analyze their click-behaviour and user-journey through a website. For that you'll need to implement Google Analytics, Omniture or any other web analytics. For a GSA-GA integration, please consult [this document](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/nl//support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/deployment/en/GSAGoogleAnalyticsGuide.pdf).

Comment: This answer isn't entirely correct. If you enable ASR (Advanced Search Reporting) you will also get the click data that you are after.
If you can, then Google Analytics is the best way to slice and dice this info but often it's not permitted if your GSA is behind the firewall.